# Why does Change Data Capture (SQL Server) job auto stop after specific duration?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, change-data-capture

I'm currently synchronizing data between Maria <--> MSSQL. That is 2 way sync.
I used SQL Server on Windows and everything works well until several days before... I switched all the test DB to Linux server, so MSSQL was run on a Docker container (the official image).

**My Env**

- MSSQL [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)
- Ubuntu (MacOS also), the CPU and RAM requirement was ensured both for device and Docker.

**My problem:**

The SQL Agent Job ran perfectly for ~10 minutes. After that, no changes were captured into `cdc.dbo_MyTrackedTable_CT`.

I want this CDC job will run forever.

I got this message:

```
Executed as user: 1b23b4b8a3ec\1b23b4b8a3ec$. 
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 217)
```

**My inspection**

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job
    @job_name = N'cdc.MyDBName_capture',
    @job_aspect = N'ALL' ;
```

Return: `last_outcome_message`

> The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User sa.  The last step to run
>   was step 2 (Change Data Capture Collection Agent).

.

Next, take a further inspection:

```
SELECT 
 job.*, '|'  as "1"
 , activity.*, '|' as "2", history.*
 , CASE
        WHEN history.[run_status] = 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN history.[run_status] = 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN history.[run_status] = 2 THEN 'Retry (step only)'
        WHEN history.[run_status] = 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN history.[run_status] = 4 THEN 'In-progress message'
        WHEN history.[run_status] = 5 THEN 'Unknown'
        ELSE 'N/A' END as Run_Status
 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity ON job.job_id = activity.job_id
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory history ON job.job_id = history.job_id
 WHERE 1=1
    AND job.name = 'cdc.MyDBName_capture'
    AND history.run_date = '20180122'
```

Return:
[See this SQL result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5ACV.png)

*Sorry I don't have enough repu to embed img, so the link instead.*

As you can see the CDC job will start and run..and..retry for 10 times, after 10times, I cannot capture changes anymore.

I need to start the job again by:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'cdc.MyDbName_capture';
```

Then foreach ~1 minutes, the job retry --> till 10 --> job was stopped ¯_(ツ)_/¯

---

### **So can you tell me why and how to fix it ??**

FYI, This is my job configuration:

```
-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-add-job-transact-sql

EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_change_job
   @job_type = N'capture',
   @maxscans = 1,
   @maxtrans = 500,
   @continuous = true,
   @pollinginterval = 1
;
```

It's also not a trigger issue right? I feel dangerous when trying to turn trigger off, but no luck was made.

```
-- Turn off recursion trigger
ALTER DATABASE MyDBName
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF;
```

Comment: This issue doesn't exist on Windows env. I still don't know why! But for anyone who struggles with this issue, plz come to MSSQL on Windows.

Comment: Please, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @icnicolau I switched from MSSQL on Linux to an installed MSSQL server version on Windows. Sometimes, logical thinking is the weakness ^^

Comment: I found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67347951/4071001), it is a bug in SQL Server 2017. It has nothing to do with the operating system, in fact I'm working on Windows from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing on SQL server 2017 running under windows server. Interestingly the same system has been running for no problems for years under SQL2012 so I am thinking it may be some bug introduced along the way.

I found with some retries the problem cleared so as a workaround I edited the job and increased the number of retries and haven't seen it again yet.

Comment: Hi Tailslide! This is probably better suited as a comment, rather than an answer. That way, people won't downvote it. Whenever you gain some reputation, try moving it to a comment. Then it'll protect your reputation points.

Comment: Thanks I have been on here like 10 years and don't have enough points to participate in anything anyways so I don't really care about them.. I did stumble upon a workaround that worked for me so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [KB4073684 - FIX: Change data capture does not work in SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4073684-fix-change-data-capture-does-not-work-in-sql-server-2017-dc398e7e-d5db-f153-c820-be58e93d4d4b).

This happens due to a declared bug:

> *Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products...*

Fix is included in [Cumulative Update 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4056498-cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2017-a8b691f7-eed8-50df-6d5d-90dd7b48b458) for SQL Server 2017. However, they recommend simply installing the latest cumulative version:

> *Each new build for SQL Server 2017 contains all the hotfixes and security fixes that were in the previous build. We recommend that you install [the latest build for SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4047329-sql-server-2017-build-versions-346e8fcd-c07c-5eeb-e10b-e3411ba8d8dd).*